# StreamStyle options of StreamPlot is not passed to Texture on ParametricPlot3D surface

Tags: plotting, textures

I have a vector field, `Pdt1` I am trying to use as the texture for a `ParametricPlot3D` plot.

When I plot the vector field with the code

```
VF1 = StreamPlot[Pdt1[u, v], {u, -a, a}, {v, -a, a}, 
  StreamStyle -> {Red, Thick}, StreamColorFunction -> None, 
  Frame -> None, ImageSize -> Large]
```

It returns the image

[image]

as expected. All well and good. When I pass this plot as a texture to `ParametricPlot3D` as done with the code

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]}, {u, -a, a}, {v, -a, a},
   PlotStyle -> {Texture[VF1]},
  PlotRange -> Full, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  ImageSize -> Large
  ]
 ]
```

What is returned is the plot but without the red or thick styling which was given in the definition of `VF1`;

[image]

How to I get the styling of `VF1` to carry over to the parametric plot?

Comment: An MWE would be helpful.

Comment: I'd suggest `PlotRangePadding -> None`, too.

Comment: I think it's a bug. Please report it to WRI.

Comment: Bug consensus, anyone?

Answer (score 4):

Convert the `StreamPlot` to an Image:

```
 a = 1;
 fun = -v + u - u^2;

VF1 =
 StreamPlot[{u, fun}, {u, -a, a}, {v, -a, a},
   StreamStyle -> {Red, Thick},
   StreamColorFunction -> None,
   Frame -> None] // Image
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[fun, {v, -a, a}, {u, -a, a}, PlotStyle -> Texture[VF1], 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Summary:**
When graphics `t` contains `Directive[]` for styling, as in the case of the OP's `StreamPlot`, use

```
PlotStyle -> Texture[t /. Directive -> Sequence]
```

to apply `t` as a texture. This prevents the internal processing,
`Texture[t] /. Directive -> List`, which wraps the directives in their own list and prevents them from being applied to the graphic primitives in `t` as originally intended. I consider this a bug.

---

*Original answer:*

```
ParametricPlot3D[..., 
  PlotStyle -> {Texture["vf1"]},
  ...] /. "vf1" -> vf1
```

[image]

Probably a bug....(The default `PlotStyle` color is applied to the `Texture[]` graphics, which cannot be overridden by `PlotStyle`, AFAICT, which is being used to apply the graphics. Catch-22?)

---

Another workaround:

```
ParametricPlot3D[...,
  PlotStyle -> Texture[Hold@vf1], 
  ] // ReleaseHold
```

---

And another (prevents the refactoring of the graphics):

```
ParametricPlot3D[..., 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[vf1 /. Directive -> Sequence]
 ]
```

And the bug seems to be that `Texture[..] /. Directive -> List` is executed by `ParametricPlot3D`, which imprisons the graphics directives in a list. So the default style, which is applied automatically at the beginning of graphics takes over.